# I want to add my project Dropdown pagination in another project in which the N-tier architecture in ASP.NET MVC is used who I can do

Tags: jquery, json, devextreme

I work on the big project in ASP.NET MVC in which the N-tier architecture is used in this project in want to add the dropdown pagination.

I build the dropdown pagination in our local project but I cannot integrate with the main project.

```
@model IEnumerable<selectbox2.Models.employee>

$(function () {
    $("#namedropdown").dxSelectBox({
        dataSource: new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
            load: function (loadOptions) {
                var pageIndex = loadOptions.skip / loadOptions.take + 1;
                var pageSize = loadOptions.take;
                var searchValue = loadOptions.searchValue;

                if (searchValue) {
                    return $.ajax({
                        url: '/Home/SearchEmployees',
                        method: 'GET',
                        data: {
                            searchValue: searchValue,
                            pageIndex: pageIndex,
                            pageSize: pageSize
                        },
                        dataType: 'json'
                    });
                } else {
                    return $.ajax({
                        url: '/Home/GetEmployees',
                        method: 'GET',
                        data: {
                            pageIndex: pageIndex,
                            pageSize: pageSize
                        },
                        dataType: 'json'
                    });
                }
            },
            paginate: true,
            pageSize: 10
        }),
        displayExpr: "Age",
        valueExpr: "pageIndex",
        placeholder: "Select Age",
        showClearButton: true,`?`
        searchEnabled: true `For search value `
    });
});
```